# redis callbacks are not firing after failure

Tags: node.js, redis

sample code that i am using:

```
var conf = require('../Config'),
    redisConf = conf.get('redis'),
    redis = require('redis'),
    redisClient = redis.createClient(redisConf.port, redisConf.host),
    redisSub = redis.createClient(redisConf.port, redisConf.host);

redisSub.subscribe('test');

redisSub.on('message', function(channel, data) {
   console.log('got message on channel: ' + channel + ' with message: ' + data);
   redisClient.get ....
});

redisSub.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("redisSub error: " + err);
});

redisSub.on('ready', function () {
   console.log('redisSub subscriber ready');
});

redisSub.on('reconnecting', function () {
   console.log('redisSub subscriber reconnecting');
});

redisSub.on('end', function () {
   console.log('redisSub subscriber ended');
});

redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("redisClient error: " + err);
});

redisClient.on('ready', function () {
   console.log('redisClient ready');
});

redisClient.on('reconnecting', function () {
   console.log('redisClient reconnecting');
});

redisClient.on('end', function () {
   console.log('redisClient ended');
});
```

I start the nodejs server, everything is working as expected.
When i restart the redis server, none of the callbacks get invoked, and i don't get any messages on the channel, and after i restart the nodejs server, the redis clients connect normally and everything works again.

Comment: When i stop/start the redis service, instead of rebooting the redis machine, everything works as expected, the callbacks get fired, redis reconnects.